# Spyder not opening the webcam result window using opencv even code is running

Tags: python, opencv, webcam

[Code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XAPJ.png)

As you can see the code is clean but still spyder is not opening the webcam even if my code is running

Comment: Please don't post your code as image

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should never place your code as an image instead just copy paste here so working with is easier for others.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `cv2.waitKey()` every time you want to update the UI.

In your code you are trying to call `cv2.imshow()` many times in the internal loop, and `cv2.waitKey()` only once in the outside loop. As a rule of the thumb, there should be one `cv2.waitKey()` call for every `cv2.imshow()` call.